# Nutch Crawl error - Input path does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch, web-crawler

I have nutch/hadoop setup with 2 datanode server. I tried to crawl some urls but nutch fails with this error:

```
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments
Fetcher: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://devcluster01:9000/user/nutch/crawl/segments/crawl_generate
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher$InputFormat.getSplits(Fetcher.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:1107)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.main(Fetcher.java:1116)
```

Can someone help me? I don't know how to solve this!
Many many Thx!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify whether nutch/crawl/segments/crawl_generate path is correct.

Either path is wrong or parse phase is not completed.

Answer (score 1):

The generate phase of nutch creates "crawl_generate" inside the segments directory. This contains the fetch list used in the fetch phase. The error that you got is because the fetch phase is unable to get the fetch list. Ensure that the output of generate is populated at the location where fetch is trying to find it.